# Ignite detecting Linux OS as WIndows while using the auto starting feature

Tags: ssh, ignite, openssh, gridgain

I have written a program which can auto start Ignite server's when provided with the details ( Machine address, username, password;etc ) of the different machines. In my case, I am trying to do so in two machines, for simplicity let's call them X and Y. I am using the Ignite version 1.9.

The code is pretty simple and calls the following API provided in the class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCluster to start the Ignite server's on remote machines :

```
Collection<ClusterStartNodeResult> org.apache.ignite.IgniteCluster.startNodes(Collection<Map<String, Object>> hosts, @Nullable Map<String, Object> dflts, boolean restart, int timeout, int maxConn) throws IgniteException
```

Upon executing the code, Ignite server starts successfully on machine X whereas it throws the following exception when it starts the Ignite Server on machine Y :

```
Caused by: com.abc.roc.exception.ROCException: One  of the Nodes failed to start properly, java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Apache Ignite cannot be auto-started on Windows from IgniteCluster.startNodes(â–’) API.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nodestart.StartNodeCallableImpl.call(StartNodeCallableImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nodestart.StartNodeCallableImpl.call(StartNodeCallableImpl.java:47)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6618)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$2.body(GridClosureProcessor.java:925)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I went a bit into the source code of the class and the method StartNodeCallableImpl.call() from where the exception was being thrown. 
The relevant snapshot of the call method mentioned above from Apache Ignite source code is as follows :

```
    JSch ssh = new JSch();

    Session ses = null;

    try {
        if (spec.key() != null)
            ssh.addIdentity(spec.key().getAbsolutePath());

        ses = ssh.getSession(spec.username(), spec.host(), spec.port());

        if (spec.password() != null)
            ses.setPassword(spec.password());

        ses.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

        ses.connect(timeout);

        boolean win = isWindows(ses);

        char separator = win ? '\\' : '/';

        spec.fixPaths(separator);

        String igniteHome = spec.igniteHome();

        if (igniteHome == null)
            igniteHome = win ? DFLT_IGNITE_HOME_WIN : DFLT_IGNITE_HOME_LINUX;

        String script = spec.script();

        if (script == null)
            script = DFLT_SCRIPT_LINUX;

        String cfg = spec.configuration();

        if (cfg == null)
            cfg = "";

        String startNodeCmd;
        String scriptOutputFileName = FILE_NAME_DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date()) + '-'
            + UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8) + ".log";

        if (win)
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Apache Ignite cannot be auto-started on Windows from IgniteCluster.startNodes(…) API.");
        else { // Assume Unix.
            int spaceIdx = script.indexOf(' ');
```

The isWindows() method is used for determining whether an OS is windows or not. The relevant snapshot of the method from Ignite source code is :

```
private boolean isWindows(Session ses) throws JSchException {
    try {
        return exec(ses, "cmd.exe") != null;
    }
    catch (IOException ignored) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The internally used exec method is as follows :

```
private String exec(Session ses, String cmd) throws JSchException, IOException {
    ChannelExec ch = null;

    try {
        ch = (ChannelExec)ses.openChannel("exec");

        ch.setCommand(cmd);

        ch.connect();

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ch.getInputStream()))) {
            return reader.readLine();
        }
    }
    finally {
        if (ch != null && ch.isConnected())
            ch.disconnect();
    }
}
```

I took the same code being used by Ignite and created a test program which will execute the on machine X and Y. The sample code written was as follows :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class JSCHSessionUtil {

public static boolean checkIgniteStyleWindow(String username, String password, String host, int port)
        throws JSchException, IOException {

    boolean isWindows = false;

    JSch ssh = new JSch();

    Session sess = ssh.getSession(username, host, port);

    sess.setPassword(password);

    sess.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

    sess.connect();

    String cmd = "cmd.exe";

    ChannelExec ch = null;

    try {
        ch = (ChannelExec) sess.openChannel("exec");

        ch.setCommand(cmd);
        ch.connect();

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ch.getInputStream()))) {

            String output = "";

            String currentLine;

            while (true) {
                currentLine = reader.readLine();
                if (currentLine == null) {
                    break;
                }
                output += currentLine;
            }

            if (output.trim().isEmpty()) {
                isWindows = false;
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("Command Output : \n"+output);
                isWindows = true;
            }

        }

    } finally {
        if (ch != null && ch.isConnected())
            ch.disconnect();
        if (sess != null && sess.isConnected())
            sess.disconnect();
    }

    return isWindows;

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JSchException, IOException {

    boolean isWindows = checkIgniteStyleWindow("username", "password", "127.0.0.1", 22);

    if (isWindows) {
        System.out.println("\nThis is a Windows OS");
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("\nThis is a Linux OS");
    }

}

}
```

The output observed on the two machines were as follows:

---

### Output for Machine X

This is a Linux OS

---

### Output for Machine Y

Command Output : 
bash: cmd.exe: command not found

This is a Windows OS

As you can see, for machine Y the error is being returned as a string instead of the API returning null ( as for machine X ). This is causing Ignite to detect a Linux OS as Windows.

I want to know a way to permanently resolve this issue.

Comment: Try to configure environment for logged in user in Y the same as in X. And open a bug in Ignite's JIRA. I see that Windows support was added in this fix, but it may work wrong in environment like yours: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7135?focusedCommentId=16319693&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16319693

Comment: Any luck with finding the root cause?

Comment: No we couldn't figure it out. We have done a workaround to start ignite servers from the script instead of auto start from code for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in Machine Y's software versions or configuration.

Can you provide details on how Machine Y is configured and the difference from Machine X? I have tried your reproducer and it determines Linux correctly.

What `sshd` version is used on Machine Y?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Interestingly, both the machines X and Y are using SSH protocol 2. I verified it using ssh -2 username@X, using -1 as an option gave the error "Protocol major versions differ: 1 vs. 2" for both the machines.

Comment: @AnikethJain can you check sshd version on both machines? `/sbin/sshd -v` should do.

Comment: Following is the output of the command on both the machines /sbin/sshd -v 
unknown option -- v
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
usage: sshd [-46DdeiqTt] [-b bits] [-C connection_spec] [-c host_cert_file]
            [-E log_file] [-f config_file] [-g login_grace_time]
            [-h host_key_file] [-k key_gen_time] [-o option] [-p port]
            [-u len].  The linux distribution is centos and the version is CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

Comment: I also tried the following command "'sudo cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -i protocol" and the output was # The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1
#Protocol 2
# HostKey for protocol version 1
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
# similar for protocol version 2   for both the machines X and Y

Comment: @AnikethJain Do you have anything unexpected in `.profile` or `.bashrc` on Machine Y by chance?

Comment: @AnikethJain also what's login shell for your user on both Machines X and Y?

Comment: There is nothing unusual in the bashrc or bash_profile files in both of the machines except a few export and alias statements used for other third-party libraries. Both the machines X and Y use bash as their login shells.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of options here.